# Vue.js reference error (event.target) not defined

Tags: vue.js, events, error-handling, mouse, referenceerror

I have a vue component that has different methods, f.ex. `mouseMove`:

```
mouseMove: function(event) {
    console.log("Event is: " + event);
    element5 = event.target
    this.elementMove = element5
    if (element5.getAttribute('data') == 'day') {
        hourPreStart = parseInt(element5.getAttribute('value'))
        dayPreStart = parseInt(element5.parentElement.firstChild.getAttribute('day-value'));
        this.hourPreEnd = hourPreStart
        this.dayPreEnd = dayPreStart
    }
    console.log(this.hourPreStart, this.dayPreStart, this.hourPreEnd, this.dayPreEnd)
},
```

When I hover over a field with my mouse I get this error:

[image]

I don't know what the problem is because `event` is defined.

[Here's](https://codeshare.io/aYMlob) the full component.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event5` is not defined (as the error stares). You have to first define `event5` to use it.
Use this

```
mouseMove: function(event) {
    console.log("Event is: " + event);
    let element5 = event.target
    this.elementMove = element5
    if (element5.getAttribute('data') == 'day') {
        let hourPreStart = parseInt(element5.getAttribute('value'))
        let dayPreStart = parseInt(element5.parentElement.firstChild.getAttribute('day-value'));
        this.hourPreEnd = hourPreStart
        this.dayPreEnd = dayPreStart
    }
    console.log(this.hourPreStart, this.dayPreStart, this.hourPreEnd, this.dayPreEnd)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using this code:

```
<tbody @mousedown='mouseDown' @mouseup='mouseUp' @mousemove='mouseMove'>
```

But you should add `$event` to handlers like this:

```
<tbody @mousemove='mouseMove($event)'>
```